# how to replace Facebook app image with profile pic using graph API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i use this code but its not working

```
$uid =$facebook->getUser(); 
$picture="http://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture?type=large";
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Could you expand a bit further?

Comment: for the wall post we use the information like : $msg = $caption = "";
  $name = "test";  
  $caption = "test";
  $desc = "test";        
  $uid =$facebook->getUser(); 
$picture="http://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture?type=large"; then wall post code $facebook->api($test, 'POST', array('message'=>$msg, 'name'=>$name, 'caption'=>$caption, 'description'=>$desc, 'picture'=>$picture... in this picture i want to show users pic??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you share, is a Graph API call to get the User Picture,
you can use this function to get the user picture:

```
function avatar($id,$size) {
    if ($size) {
        $size = '?type='.$size.'';
    }
    return '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture'.$size.'" alt="" />';
}
```

i pass a second variable for the picture size,
so you can use it like this:

```
echo avatar($uid,'square');
```